# A group of friends at a restaurant.

Tags: word-problem, logic-grid

Four groups of four friends each are having dinner at a restaurant. There are four tables, table A, B, C, and D, seating four each, arranged in a square like so.

A B

C D

Each table looks like this.

```
     XX
```

(Center of table)

```
     XX
```

Table A contains Alfred, Aisha, Andrew, and Amy.

Table B contains Bailey, Brian, Blake, and Beatrice.

Table C contains Charlie, Cathy, Cole, and Cindy

Table D contains Dale, Dorothy, Duncan, and Debbie

Where does everyone sit if

-Amy sits here at table A
(Marked with an A)

xA

xx

- Bailey sits across the tables to Amy's left.
- Andrew wanted to discuss with Amy, and thus sat across from her.
- Brian accidentally flung his spoon to his right, hitting Blake on the head.
- Andrew and Alfred are not on good terms and chose to sit diagonal from one another.
- Table C is comprised of married couples on each side.
- Whenever Charlie turns around, he sees Andrew.
- The person across to the left of the person in front of Cathy, who is married to Cole, is often mistaken for a character from *The Wizard of Oz*, because she shares a name with the main character.
- Duncan tried to sit alone, but Debbie made him sit diagonal to her.
- Dale is nervous because Duncan keeps staring straight forward at him while they eat.

This should be enough information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The friends seem to be sitting in this arrangement:

> [image]

Comment: Great Job! I didn't know if it would be enough, but it was.